# Neo4j / Cypher - find path but middle nodes of this path can't be of type X

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this code for finding the shortest path:

```
p=shortestPath((startNode)-[*..10]-(endNode))
```

Now I would like to add a condition that none of middle nodes can be of X type. Only the first node has an X type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((startNode)-[*..10]-(endNode))
WHERE none(node IN nodes(p)[1..-1] WHERE node:X)
```

The key is to omit the first and the last node from the filter like so:

```
nodes(p)[1..-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worth reading, in order to try to avoid that Cypher falls back to the slow algo

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/